# This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key issue

Tags: ios, swift, sigabrt

I keep running into a SIGABRT error with the message

```
"2017-04-20 17:37:54.872 SepsisHub[3670:1670129] Unknown class _TtC10Sepsis_Hub14ViewController in Interface Builder file.
2017-04-20 17:38:54.903 SepsisHub[3670:1670129] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x7fcb8ae03240> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key FirstHour.'"
```

however,  I cannot find a connection that is missing in either the storyboard or .swift file. There are no error messages when building, and it seems like for some reason the program cant find the IBOutlet and I don't understand why considering I've deleted them all and reconnected multiple times in both the swift file and the storyboard connector with no change.

Thank you for any assistance. Further screenshots will be provided if needed.

Comment: in xib/storyboard, right click on your `Files Owner`  / `ViewController`  to see the list of outlets. check for any outlet that does not exist in your class.

Answer (score 6):

In your `xib/storyboard,` right click on your `Files Owner` / `ViewController` to see the list of outlets. check for any outlet that does not exist in your class. This could happen when you connected an `IBOutlet` then removed or renamed the property. Example below shows an `IBOutlet` named `labelIDeleted` shows warning because I removed the property from my class

[image]

EDIT:

Also check if your `ViewController` is assigned correct class.
[image]

Comment: http://imgur.com/6uJlur7

There is no such alert so im not sure what to do

Comment: @user7898292 check edited answer

Comment: class was already set as ViewController, and the swift file was ViewController.swift

Comment: @user7898292 did you make sure it is not in separate module?